# how to compare emails with trigger in two objects

Tags: trigger, leads, apex-email-service

Good morning, I'm new to the apex trigger world and I have a problem. I need to create a trigger that compares me to the emails of leads and if it coincides with an email of "Candidato_wifi". Do not believe, my code only checks the first email when I make a massive data load. Could you help me?

```
trigger CheckEmail on Lead (before insert) {
    List<Candidato_wifi__c> a1=[Select id from Candidato_wifi__c 
                                    where Email__c=:trigger.new[0].email];
    if(a1.size()>0)
    {
        trigger.new[0].email.addError('Lead Email already Exist');
    }
}
```

Comment: The [Bulk Apex](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_bulk) module on Salesforce Trailhead is a good way to learn how to build triggers to handle bulk data.

Answer (score 1):

You are only checking first lead record which you insert. i.e, `trigger.new[0]`. You need to bulkify your code to handle all the Lead records. Try this code snippet.

```
trigger CheckEmail on Lead (before insert) {
    Set<String> emailSet = new Set<String>();
    for(Candidato_wifi__c c: [Select Id,Email__c From Candidato_wifi__c Limit :(Limits.getLimitQueryRows() - Limits.getQueryRows())]){
        emailSet.add(c.Email__c);
    }
    for(Lead l :Trigger.new){
        if(emailSet.contains(l.Email)){
            l.email.addError('Lead Email already Exist');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not quite; this trigger will fail when you reach 50k records in the org.